# For User before Update

Tags: php, search

I have made an API to insert data of 7 fields (fullname, city, bloodgroup, password, mobileno, lastdonated, created_date) in a mysql database using INSERT, please help me to add some code to search if the user is already added using the mobileno field and only then add the record else show the message "User already exists".

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
if(count($_REQUEST) > 0)
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "creative_bloodapp", "PasSwORd", 'creative_bldapp');
        $fullname           =$_POST['fullname'];
        $city               =$_POST['city'];
        $bloodgroup         =$_POST['bloodgroup'];
        $password           =$_POST['password'];
        $mobileno           =$_POST['mobileno'];
        $lastdonated        =$_POST['lastdonated'];
        $created_date       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO register (fullname, city, bloodgroup, password, mobileno, lastdonated, created_date) VALUES ('" . $fullname . "','" . $city . "','" . $bloodgroup . "','" . $password . "','" . $mobileno . "','" . $lastdonated . "','". $created_date . "');";
    $qur = $conn->query($sql);
    if($qur){
        $query="SELECT * FROM register ORDER BY mobileno DESC LIMIT 1;";
        $data=array();
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        response(1,"User has been registered!",$row);
    }else{
        mysqli_close($conn);
        response(0,"Not Registered!",NULL);
    }
}
else
{
    response(0,"Not Registered!",NULL);
}
function response($status,$status_message,$data)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 ".$status);
    $response['status']=$status;
    $response['status_message']=$status_message;
    $response['data']=$data;
    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}
?>
```

Comment: just add a simple select count before the insertion begins first, it serves as your checker whether the mobile exists already or not, by the way, why not use prepared statements, you're using mysqli anyways

Comment: before the insert query do a select query to check if $mobileno   eqauls something in the database i.e $res = query(SELECT * FROM table where mobileno = '$mobileno') if(count($res) >=1) then echo "user exists"; exit;

Comment: Please add also some SQL injection prevention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for something like this; I changed some queries and re-wrote a part for you. Also added `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
if(count($_REQUEST) > 0)
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "creative_bloodapp", "PasSwORd", 'creative_bldapp');
    $fullname           = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fullname']);
    $city               = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['city']);
    $bloodgroup         = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bloodgroup']);
    $password           = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $mobileno           = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mobileno']);
    $lastdonated        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastdonated']);
    $created_date       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    $query="SELECT * FROM register  WHERE mobileno = '".$mobileno."'";
    $qur=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if(count(mysqli_num_rows($qur) !== 0)){
        $data=array();
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        response(1,"User has been registered!",$row);
    }else{
        $sql = "INSERT INTO register (fullname, city, bloodgroup, password, mobileno, lastdonated, created_date) VALUES ('" . $fullname . "','" . $city . "','" . $bloodgroup . "','" . $password . "','" . $mobileno . "','" . $lastdonated . "','". $created_date . "');";
        $qur=mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        response(0,"Not Registered!",NULL);
    }
}
else
{
    response(0,"Not Registered!",NULL);
}
function response($status,$status_message,$data)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 ".$status);
    $response['status']=$status;
    $response['status_message']=$status_message;
    $response['data']=$data;
    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Make it mobileno unique key so

```
if($qur) 
{
// new mobileno
//add it will take 
}
else
{
// repeated i will not accept, you put mobileno exist.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
if(count($_REQUEST) > 0)
{
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "creative_bloodapp", "PasSwORd", 'creative_bldapp');
    $fullname           = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fullname']);
    $city               = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['city']);
    $bloodgroup         = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['bloodgroup']);
    $password           = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $mobileno           = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mobileno']);
    $lastdonated        = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastdonated']);
    $created_date       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $verifysql = "select id from register where mobileno='".$mobileno."'";
    $qur = $conn->query($verifysql);
    if($qur->num_rows == 0){
       $sql = "INSERT INTO register (fullname, city, bloodgroup, password, mobileno, lastdonated, created_date) VALUES ('" . $fullname . "','" . $city . "','" . $bloodgroup . "','" . $password . "','" . $mobileno . "','" . $lastdonated . "','". $created_date . "');";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);
       if($result){
          mysqli_close($conn);
          response(200,"User has been registered!",$row);
       }else{
          mysqli_close($conn);
          response(500,"Registeration Failed",NULL);
       }
    }
    else{ 
        mysqli_close($conn);
        response(409,"User Already Exists!",NULL);
    }
}
else
{
  response(400,"Not Registered!",NULL);
}
```